# is it possible to assign CSS to the content property of css?

Tags: css

My main goal its to add content to beginning of a div using the CSS content property.I was able to do that using the following CSS code:

```
   .advads::before {
        content: "Advertisement";
        display: block;
    }
```

Now the problem is i need to assign some css to the content, bacsically `background-color` and some `padding`. is there a way to do that WITHOUT adding HTML?

what i'm actually trying to achieve its to add the "ADVERTISEMENT" title like in the following example: [link to example](http://ecolitics.com/25-celebrities-who-are-aging-horribly/)
thx

Comment: The `content` property (despite the name) should not hold actual content. It's intended as a styling enhancement not a content holder. Use an actual element instead.

Comment: You can use jquery to achieve that.

Comment: I think better solution is to use jquery but you can do this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/230/

Comment: See also [A Whole Bunch of Amazing Stuff Pseudo Elements Can Do](https://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can style [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) like any other:

```css
.advads {
    width:200px;
    height:80px;
    background:#aaa;
    position:relative;
}
.advads:after {
    content:"Advertisement";
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    color:#000;   
    width:100px;
    margin:auto;
    background:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    padding:4px;
}
.advads:before {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background:#ffffff;
    color:#000;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    margin-top:11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="advads">Ad</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply add the necessary properties directly to the rules for the pseudo-element, like so:

```
.advads::before{
    background:red;
    content:"Advertisement";
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
}
```

Comment: that will influence the entire div...im looking to influence only the content property

Comment: Did you even try it? Any styles you add to that rule will *only* be applied to that particular `before` pseudo-element.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way will be using semantic HTML and pseudoelements, if you want to achieve something like in the provided example, this is the way:

```css
.heading {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
}
.heading:before {
  content: "";
  border-top: solid 1px #b9b9b9;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  display: block;
}
.heading h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline;
  padding: 11px;
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<header class="heading">
  <h3>Advertisement</h3>
</header>
```